# Delete files in Hadoop file system (hdfs)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I left a sqoop job running and it completely filled the hdfs(100%). Now i cannot delete the files in Hdfs. It is giving me an execption

```
    # hdfs dfs -rm -skipTrash /TEST_FILE 
    rmr: Cannot delete /TEST_FILE. Name node is in safe mode.
```

I used `hdfs dfsadmin -safemode` to leave out of safe mode.

```
    [hdfs@sandbox /]$ hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
    Safe mode is OFF
```

But when i try again deleting the file using `hdfs dfs -rm -skipTrash /TEST_FILE` iam getting error message that `NameNode is in safemode`

I am unable to leave safemode and delete the file.

can anyone help me how to get out of safemode and delete the file?

Comment: Is it single-node cluster? what is the data replication factor in your cluster?

Comment: Check whether namenode has atleast 1 active datanode and check storage in your disk.

Comment: Try this `hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave`

Comment: It is a single node cluster and the data replication factor is 1. I have also checked the disk storage and it is full.

Comment: try "hadoop fs -expunge" followed by "sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave", this will some how empty your  trash. so that you may left with some space.

Comment: Check if **DataNode** and **NameNode** is running using `jps` command.

Answer (score 0):

Namenode cannot be brought out of safe mode with the command "hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave" unless you are really cleaning up something . if you dont do anything and use the command , the name node will go back to safe mode .
Since you are using the single node cluster , you can try cleaning up your log directories /var/log/ ... and bring the name node out of safe mode and delete the hdfs directory left by sqoop